# MongoDB find last submission for each user

Tags: python, linux, mongodb, pymongo

I have many documents with such structure:

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("52be9d8dbfbc2c17e6a4e06b"),
"contest" : "Teamcode",
"data" : [
    {
        "status" : "0",
        "message" : "Correct",
        "runtime" : 0.10917782783508301,
        "score" : 20
    },
    {
        "status" : "0",
        "message" : "Correct",
        "runtime" : 0.12033200263977051,
        "score" : 20
    },
    {
        "status" : "0",
        "message" : "Correct",
        "runtime" : 0.35556793212890625,
        "score" : 20
    },
    {
        "status" : "0",
        "message" : "Correct",
        "runtime" : 1.8789710998535156,
        "score" : 20
    },
    {
        "status" : "0",
        "message" : "Correct",
        "runtime" : 0.9521079063415527,
        "score" : 20
    }
],
"id" : 242,
"lang" : "c",
"problem" : "roate",
"result" : [ ],
"score" : 100,
"status" : "done",
"time" : 1388223885.051975,
"user" : {
    "email" : "orizont1",
    "user_class" : 0,
    "name" : "orizont1"
}
   }
```

Each user has many submissions for each problem in one contest.
I have variable called "contest", and I want to take the last submission of each user per each problem. I use pymongo.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Query can be formed like this:

for each problem (for say Teamcode problem), give me last submission of all users

-> while querying you need to keep in mind that size of object array (data) is greater than equal to 1.

-> query:  { "contest": "Teamcode" , "data": { $size: {$gte:1} } }

-> projection: {"data":{$slice:-1}, id:1}. $slice:-1 will give you last element of object array (data) in each document which match the query.

For **$slice** read this:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/#proj._S_slice

```
 YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME.find( { "contest": "Teamcode" , "data": { $size: {$gte:1} } }, {"data":{$slice:-1}, id:1} )
```

Comment: I tried but DB gave me nothing. I tried without slicing and also no result: 
`db.submissions.find( { "contest": "Teamcode" , "data": { $size: {$gte:1} } } )`

Comment: try just this: YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME.find( { "contest": "Teamcode" }, {"data":{$slice:-1}, id:1} )